# Partial preamble precompilation? (luaLaTeX document with glossaries (and shell-escape, if possible))

Tags: compiling, glossaries, shell-escape

## Main concern

Hi, I've figured out how to use `mylatexformat.ltx` to precompile a preamble and then use the precompiled `.fmt` to compile a separate file that does not contain a preamble, but rather uses the precompiled preamble instead...

However, I have run into some issues with the `glossaries` package. My document compiles just fine when the preamble is not precompiled, it just takes a very long time, much of which is spent re-loading the packages and fonts each run. The preamble also precompiles without error (if I don't use the `minted` package --see below). However, for some reason the glossary definitions don't seem to be included in the precompiled preamble, even though they are loaded/defined in the preamble file...

Is there a way to make this work? Other than creating spoof definitions for the `glossaries` package macros for when I want to use the precompiled preamble?

## Additional concern

I also would like to use the `minted` package, and not being able to use it in the precompiled preamble isn't the hugest deal, but it is annoying. `lyluatex` also requires the `--shell-escape` option, but it hasn't thrown an error yet (I also currently have commented out the parts where I use macros from `lyluatex`, for time reasons, so it's hard to tell if it will actually work).

Do you know if it's okay to use `--shell-escape` for the precompilation and/or for the preamble? Or does `minted` just not work with precompilation? When I try to use it, LaTeX maxes out on 100 errors just at `\begin{document}` (aka the first line of my non-preamble file), citing an "attempt to index a nil value (global shellesc)".

*(I know I could split these up into two separate questions, but I feel they may be related in some way.)*

Comment: I suppose my main question is if it is possible to precompile parts of the preamble, and leave other parts to be evaluated (still as preamble and not in between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) later on.

Comment: In answer to your main question: yes. However, this question doesn't seem to be either of the two questions you ask.

Comment: @cfr How would I go about having two preambles, though? I've sort of noticed that using my precompiled preamble means that an error occurs if I try to do any preamble-y stuff in the non-precompiled file.

Comment: I don't know. I'd assume you could, but I've never done it. I've never bothered with precompiling preamble stuff at all.